# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined as

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

When I compile my C# project in MonoDevelop, I get the following error:

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined as 'byte' and 'int' convert implicitly to each other`

Code Snippet:

```
byte oldType = type;
type = bindings[type];
//Ignores updating blocks that are the same and send block only to the player
if (b == (byte)((painting || action == 1) ? type : 0))
{
    if (painting || oldType != type) { SendBlockchange(x, y, z, b); } return;
}
```

This is the line that is highlighted in the error:

`if (b == (byte)((painting || action == 1) ? type : 0))`

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The conditional operator is an expression and thus needs a return type, and both paths have to have the same return type.

```
(painting || action == 1) ? type : (byte)0
```

Comment: How about in the case where the parameter is expected to be any type such as `String.Format("value: {0}", (value == null) ? : "null" : value)` where value is of type `int?`?

Answer (score 5):

There is no implicit conversion between `byte` and `int`, so you need to specify one in the results of the ternary operator:

```
? type : (byte)0
```

Both return types on this operator need to either be the same or have an implicit conversion defined in order to work.

From MSDN [`?: Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.